# Problemas com url amigável no spring mvc

Tags: java, jsf, spring-mvc, url-amigável

ao incluir uma ultima página no meu projeto obtive um problema de url, do qual, não consegui identificar o problema.

Cenário JSF:

- Módulo Atedimento: href="atendimento/cliente"
- Detalhes do cliente: href="cliente/${nrPasta}"
- Módulo Atedimento: href="atendimento/cliente"

Acesso o módulo de atendimento, este listará todos os clientes cadastrados.
Seleciono um dos clientes e acesso o detalhes do mesmo, que me leva a url "app/atendimento/cliente/123", ate este ponto funciona normalmente, porem, se o usuário resolver clicar novamente no link do módulo a url carregada será "app/atendimento/cliente/atendimento/cliente".

```
@RequestMapping("/atendimento")
public class Atendimento {

  @RequestMapping("/cliente")
  public String atendimentoCliente(){};

  @RequestMapping("/{nrPasta}")
  public String atendimentoDetalhes(){}
```

URL base: localhost:8084/app/

Portanto, aguem tem alguma idéia do que pode estar acontecendo, pois eu não estou identificando meu erro.

Atendimento.jsf

```
<tbody>
<c:forEach items="${cliente}" var="cl">
 <tr>
  <td>${cl.nrPasta}</td>
  <td>${cl.nome}</td>
  <td class="hidden-480">
    <span class="label label-sm label-success">Novo</span>
  </td>
  <td>
   <div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs action-buttons">
    <a class="blue" href="cliente/${cl.nrPasta}">
     <i class="ace-icon fa fa-search-plus bigger-130"></i>
    </a>
   </div>
  <div class="hidden-md hidden-lg">
   <div class="inline pos-rel">
    <button class="btn btn-minier btn-yellow dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-position="auto">
     <i class="ace-icon fa fa-caret-down icon-only bigger-120"></i>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-only-icon dropdown-yellow dropdown-menu-right dropdown-caret dropdown-close">
     <li>
      <a href="cliente/${cl.nrPasta}" class="tooltip-info" data-rel="tooltip" title="View">
      <span class="blue">
       <i class="ace-icon fa fa-search-plus bigger-120"></i>
      </span>
     </a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</tbody><!-- tbody -->
```

Módulo com link Atendimento:

```
<ul class="submenu">
  <li class="">
    <a href="atendimento/cliente">
     <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
      Atendimento
    </a>
    <b class="arrow"></b>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Coloca o código da página que tem o botão para navegar para o link do módulo nos detalhes do cliente.

Answer (score 0):

Não é considerado boa prática colocar o contexto da aplicação Web ou o endereço completo *hardcoded* na página. Se você mudar qualquer coisa, depois vai ter que procurar em todo o projeto.

Você está usando o `href` com o caminho relativo, então `atendimento/cliente` será incluído no final de qualquer caminho onde esse link apareça.

Para referenciar diretamente o diretório `atendimento`, na raiz da sua aplicação, use

`<a href="/atendimento/cliente">`

**Editado**

Considerando que o contexto da aplicação é removido quando você usa o caminho absoluto e você está criando uma página JSF, tente usar a tag [`<h:link>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/link.html)

`<h:link value="Texto" outcome="/atendimento/cliente" />`

Não esqueça de incluir os *namespaces* na sua tag `<html>`:

`xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"`

Comment: Já utilizei o exemplo informado, porem, o endereço "/app/" será apagado e minha aplicação não encontrará a url "localhost:8084/atendimento/cliente".
Concordo sobre a má prática, porem, não visualizei outra melhor e simples, se possível pode me informar possíveis soluções.

Comment: Eu estava analisando o context, tipo ${pageContext.request.contextPath}, mas já que cogitou a não utilizar vou avaliar a forma sugerida.